# Get Result from Stored procedure MySql PHP in HTML Table

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have stored procedure in database:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `billing`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Pivot`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Pivot`(
    IN tbl_name VARCHAR(99),       -- table name (or db.tbl)
    IN base_cols VARCHAR(99),      -- column(s) on the left, separated by commas
    IN pivot_col VARCHAR(64),      -- name of column to put across the top
    IN tally_col VARCHAR(64),      -- name of column to SUM up
    IN where_clause VARCHAR(99),   -- empty string or "WHERE ..."
    IN order_by VARCHAR(99)        -- empty string or "ORDER BY ..."; usually the base_cols
    )
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN
    -- Find the distinct values
    -- Build the SUM()s
    SET @subq = CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT ', pivot_col, ' AS val ',
                    ' FROM ', tbl_name, ' ', where_clause, ' ORDER BY 1');
    -- select @subq;
    SET @cc1 = "CONCAT('SUM(IF(&p = ', &v, ', &t, 0)) AS ', &v)";
    SET @cc2 = REPLACE(@cc1, '&p', pivot_col);
    SET @cc3 = REPLACE(@cc2, '&t', tally_col);
    -- select @cc2, @cc3;
    SET @qval = CONCAT("'\"', val, '\"'");
    -- select @qval;
    SET @cc4 = REPLACE(@cc3, '&v', @qval);
    -- select @cc4;
    SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;   -- just in case
    SET @stmt = CONCAT(
            'SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(', @cc4, ' SEPARATOR ",\n")  INTO @sums',
            ' FROM ( ', @subq, ' ) AS top');
     SELECT @stmt;
    PREPARE _sql FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE _sql;                      -- Intermediate step: build SQL for columns
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _sql;
    -- Construct the query and perform it
    SET @stmt2 = CONCAT(
            'SELECT ',
                base_cols, ',\n',
                @sums,
                ',\n SUM(', tally_col, ') AS Total'
            '\n FROM ', tbl_name, ' ',
            where_clause,
            ' GROUP BY ', base_cols,
            '\n WITH ROLLUP',
            '\n', order_by
        );
    SELECT @stmt2;                    -- The statement that generates the result
    PREPARE _sql FROM @stmt2;
    EXECUTE _sql;                     -- The resulting pivot table ouput
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _sql;
    -- For debugging / tweaking, SELECT the various @variables after CALLing.
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

When i pass a SQL statement i want to capture the final result in rows with column headers and pass it to the HTML Table output on PHP.

> CALL Pivot('production', 'product_name', 'market', 'forcast_qty',
>   \"WHERE production_date = '2015-12-31'\", '');

So far when i code the following procedure to get the output i am getting a array but not the end result of the stored procedure.

```
if(isset($_POST['planned_forecast']))
{
if(isset($_POST['production_date'])){ $date_prod = $_POST['production_date']; } 
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("CALL Pivot('production', 'product_name', 'market', 'forcast_qty', \"WHERE production_date = '2015-12-31'\", '');");
$stmt->execute();
while ($row  = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
print_r($row);
}
echo '
<thead>';
   echo '
</thead>
';
echo '
<tbody>
   ';
   echo '
   <tr>
      ';
      echo '
      <td></td>
      ';
      echo '
   </tr>
   ';
   echo '
</tbody>
';
echo '</table>';
echo '<input hidden="true" name="date_prod" type="text" value="'.$date_prod.'"/>';
echo '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default waves-effect waves-light" name="btn-editforcast" id="btn-editforcast">Update</button>';
}
```

Result:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [@stmt] => SELECT
>   GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('SUM(IF(market = ', '"', val, '"', ', forcast_qty,
>   0)) AS ', '"', val, '"') SEPARATOR ", ") INTO @sums FROM ( SELECT
>   DISTINCT market AS val FROM production WHERE production_date =
>   '2015-12-31' ORDER BY 1 ) AS top ) )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can simplify the stored procedure and use something like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `billing`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Pivot`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Pivot`(
    IN tbl_name VARCHAR(99),       -- table name (or db.tbl)
    IN base_cols VARCHAR(99),      -- column(s) on the left, separated by commas
    IN pivot_col VARCHAR(64),      -- name of column to put across the top
    IN tally_col VARCHAR(64),      -- name of column to SUM up
    IN where_clause VARCHAR(99),   -- empty string or "WHERE ..."
    IN order_by VARCHAR(99)        -- empty string or "ORDER BY ..."; usually the base_cols
    )
    DETERMINISTIC
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
BEGIN

    -- Prepare the "pivot" part of the query
    SET @stmt = CONCAT(

        "SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(\" SUM(\" ",
        "                    \"   CASE WHEN ", pivot_col, "='\", ", pivot_col, ", \"'\"  ",
        "                    \"         THEN ", tally_col, "\"  ",
        "                    \"         ELSE 0\"  ",
        "                    \"    END\"  ",
        "                    \") AS '\", ", pivot_col, ", \"'\n\") as stmt FROM (select distinct ", pivot_col, " FROM ", tbl_name, ") A INTO @sum_clause"    
    );


    PREPARE _sql FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE _sql;                     
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _sql;

        -- Prepare and execute the query itself
    SET @stmt = CONCAT(
        "SELECT ", base_cols, ", ", 
        @sum_clause,
        ", SUM(", tally_col, ") as 'Total qty'"
        " FROM ", tbl_name, " \n" ,
        where_clause, "\n",
        " GROUP BY ", base_cols
        );

    PREPARE _sql FROM @stmt;
    EXECUTE _sql;                     
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _sql;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I can't guarantee that it works for all cases, but it works for the parameters that you are using in your example, and produces the same results as the ones in the original question.

Comment: It did not work.. :( I am looking to get the output of final result of the procedure and populate that into php html tabe

Comment: Let's start by checking the stored procedure itself. 

If you call the stored procedure manually, does it return the correct results? Or does it return incorrect results? An error? Nothing?

Comment: It gives the correct result let me update and share the screenshot

Comment: This worked the above example and is giving out the array. The only thing missing is a Total at the end

Comment: I forgot the where clause. I'll add it in the next iteration. 

What do you mean by "a Total at the end? There were no total in your initial example. What does that total include and how is it presented?

Comment: The sum of the row marked as total qty at the end of the row. Rest is working perfect thank you so much..

Comment: Thank you for the update. Can i alter the procedure to make it take multiple where conditions or is it good to go already?

Comment: The procedure uses the parameter as it is passed. If you need multiple conditions, put them in the parameter with correct parenthesis and it should work properly.

Comment: Yup just checked and made few changes as required. Issues is resolved :)